# urllib.request.urlopen Unknown file extension

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, urllib

I am trying to download a image from a URL using urllib and PIL. The url has no file extension, but the image is a jpg. I get a 'unknown file extension: ' error.

https://rimh2.domainstatic.com.au/afYrRIa5-BhhWW2t7eD7-cEOKro=/fit-in/1920x1080/filters:format(jpeg):quality(80):no_upscale()/http://b.domainstatic.com.au.s3-website-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/2015800146_1_1_191119_062711-w800-h600

```
image = Image.open(urllib.request.urlopen(i))
image.save('path')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try This Method**

```
import urllib.request
urllib.request.urlretrieve("http://www.text.com/news/media/2019/12/text.jpg", 
"image/filename.jpg")
```

Comment: can I save it to a specific path and not just the current directory this way?

Comment: @adam , yes you can save it , using this method

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save this file only, then go with @Bloody Programmer's answer but if you're going to process it as an image and just wanted to save it before processing, use

```
image.save('filename.jpg')
```

(Specify the extension)

Answer (score 0):

```
from urllib import request
from PIL import Image     

i = 'https://rimh2.domainstatic.com.au/afYrRIa5-BhhWW2t7eD7-cEOKro=/fit-in/1920x1080/filters:format(jpeg):quality(80):no_upscale()/http://b.domainstatic.com.au.s3-website-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/2015800146_1_1_191119_062711-w800-h600'

img = Image.open(request.urlopen(i))
img = img.save('image.jpg')
```